# As I got the contrapositive of this statement, how does e) necessarily follows from this?

Tags: propositional-calculus

An electronic circuit contains three light bulbs, X, Y and Z, which are each either on or off at
any particular time. It is known that if bulb X is off or bulb Y is on, then bulb Z is on.
Which one of these statements necessarily follows from this?

A. If bulb Z is on, then bulb X is off or bulb Y is on.

B. If bulb Z is on, then bulb X is on and bulb Y is off.

C. If bulb Z is on, then bulb X is on or bulb Y is on.

D. If bulb Z is off, then bulb X is off and bulb Y is off.

E. If bulb Z is off, then bulb X is on or bulb Y is off.

F. If bulb Z is off, then bulb X is on and bulb Y is on.

---

The contrapositive of the given statement is If bulb Z is off, then bulb X is on and bulb Y is off. However, apparently, there is no such choice in the given choices.

Comment: Did you try to put this into a logical expression?

Comment: actly the answer is e,but i dont know why

Comment: @Kevin You correctly found the the contrapositive ....now  think a little about what that says ... and you'll see how e) logically follows from that. That is, answer e) is not *equivalent* to the original statement, but it does logically *follow* from it

Comment: @Bram28 im sorry, could u please be more detail oriented on how does it follow from it

Comment: @Kevin remember the logical "or" is inclusive. So, if I tell you that snow is white and grass is green, does it follow (in logic) that snow is white or grass is green?

Comment: oh i see,thx so much @Bram28

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Comment: I've edited your thoughts into your question (taken from the comment you posted to a wrong answer). Next time, please include such attempts in the question, so that we can better address your inquiry (and your question wouldn't have been closed). =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, I gather you correctly found the contrapositive (you should really add that to your post ... in general, you should always add your work to your post). So, that is:

If Z is off, then X is on and Y is off

Now, this is almost the same as answer e) ... except in e) you have an 'or' rather than an 'and'

But, remember that in logic the 'or' is inclusive. So, if it is true that 'P and Q', then it follows that 'P or Q'.

Likewise, if Z is off, we know X is on and Y is off. But then it is also true that X is on or Y is off. So, if Z is off, then X is on or Y is off

So, the answer is e). e) is not logically *equivalent* to the original statement but, as we saw, it does logically *follow* from it, and that is what the question asked.